# Original publication for YAMNet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, dataset

I want to find the original research paper the Developer DAN ELLIS published about YAMNet.

A breif description about YAMNet is a pre-trained deep neural network that can predict audio events from 521 classes, such as laughter, barking, or a siren. In this tutorial you will learn how to: Load and use the YAMNet model for inference. Build a new model using the YAMNet embeddings to classify cat and dog sounds.

Link to the author - https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=1H4HuCkAAAAJ&view_op=list_works&sortby=pubdate

I tried searching online but with no luck.